# Bash Regular Expression Condition

Tags: regex, bash, conditional-statements

I have a regular expression that I need to verify. The regular expression has double quotes in it, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly escape them.

First attempt, doesn't work as the quotes are not escaped.

```
while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ "<a href="(.+)">HTTP</a>" ]]; then
    SOURCE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    break
  fi
done < tmp/source.html

echo "{$SOURCE}" #output = {"link.html"} (with double quotes)
```

How can I properly run this so the output is *link.html* without double quotes.

I have tried...

```
while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ "<a href=/"(.+)/">HTTP</a>" ]]; then
    SOURCE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    break
  fi
done < tmp/source.html

echo "{$SOURCE}" #output = {}
```

Without luck. Can someone please help me so I can stop beating my head on my desk? I am not great with Bash. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `\\`, its now the universal escape character regognized around the world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's always best to put your regex in a variable.

```
pattern='<a href="(.+)">HTTP</a>'
while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
    SOURCE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    break
  fi
done < tmp/source.html

echo "{$SOURCE}" #output = {link.html} (without double quotes)
```

If you quote the right hand side (the pattern), it changes the match from regex to a simple string equal (`=~` effectively becomes `==`).

As a side note, escaping is done with backslashes (`\`) rather than slashes (`/`), but that would not help your situation because of the outer quotes as mentioned in my previous paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, any idea what the difference is between putting it in a variable and writing it directly into the `[[ $line =~ pattern ]]` block?

Comment: @chw21: Quoting the pattern to allow characters such as spaces in it causes the pattern to be treated as a simple string instead of a regex and the match to be equivalent to `==` instead of `=~`. It's much easier and less awkward to do quoting and escaping in a variable assignment.

Comment: And between Bash 3.1 and 3.2 they changed the behavior of quotes on the right side to cause whatever is between them to be interpreted literally as a string instead of just grouping things or escaping whitespace which can trip a lot of people up (like myself repeatedly for instance).

Answer (score 2):

```
$line =~ "<a href=\"(.+)\">HTTP</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend always use a variable when specifying the regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE=
url_re='<a href="(.+)">HTTP</a>'
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $url_re ]]; then
        SOURCE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        break
    fi
done < test.txt

echo $SOURCE # http://example.com/

# test.txt contents:
# <a href="http://example.com/">HTTP</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `"<a href="""(.+)""">HTTP</a>"`

Edit, well try this

`"<a href="\""(.+)"\"">HTTP</a>"`

or

`'<a href="(.+)">HTTP</a>'`

or

`'<a href='\"'(.+)'\"'>HTTP</a>'`  <-- this will give the right syntax in Bash, as for the regex (.+), don't know how that will play

Edit, what do you get when you use this regex `"<a href=(.+)>HTTP</a>"`  ??

Comment: Output is still {"link.html"}

Comment: With all three, the output is {}

Answer (score 0):

Without an intermediate variable (i.e. use the regex directly after =~), it works only if the regex pattern doesn't have certain characters (space, < or >, etc.) and you remove the quotes around the regex, or if the regex is a plain alphanumeric string

```
$ x='Hello'
$ [[ $x =~ ^H ]] && echo OK
OK
$ [[ $x =~ 'H' ]] && echo OK
OK
$ [[ $x =~ H ]] && echo OK
OK
```

I stumbled across this page while looking for an explanation on the design of bash that generally doesn't allow you to use regex directly after =~. For example

```
$ re='^H'
$ [[ $x =~ $re ]] && echo OK
OK
```

works as expected, while

```
$ [[ $x =~ '^H' ]] && echo OK
```

does not. I personally always put the regex in a variable first. But I still wonder why bash is designed this way. You can argue assigning the regex to a variable first would overall make the code look neater. Any other reason? If a regex is not supposed to be interpreted as a string, bash could use other ways to represent it. For example, Perl uses slashes, /regex/, or more explicitly m/regex/.